# Get Current User Id in jBPM

Tags: java, jbpm

I am using jBPM 6.1.0 and trying to fire a rest service from my jBPM using REST Service Task.

I need to pass the current logged in user id to the reset service. For that, I would like to know how to get the current logged in user id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a documented method to get an User or a collection of them.

However if you know the User to make the REST api call, you could pass the same string as a *parameter* (process variable) when you start a new process instance and then use that *variable* as a parameter in your REST service task.

The notation to pass variables to the REST Service Task URL is:

```
http://server.company.com/rest/service?parameter=#{process_variable}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only way to invoke REST calls for a certain user is using his credentials in each call, embedding it in the URL like:

```
http://user:password@server.address.com/business-central/rest
```

You can't impersonate another user to make a call. The best you can do is use the 'Administrator' account in order to ***delegate***, ***forward*** and ***release*** tasks.

Comment: Hi, I am not referring to the REST API of jBPM. I have a REST service hosted on a different server which needs to be invoked from jBPM REST Service Task. And I need to pass the logged in user id as a parameter to the external REST Service. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, my bad... One thing you can do is save the user_id as a process variable when you create the process, and then pass this process variable to the URL parameter to the REST task. Hope it helps.

Comment: But how will I fill the value into user_id process variable?

Comment: In jBPM user_ids are just strings. If you know the user_id before you start the process, you can pass it as a process variable. In fact, you have to know it to create the process instance in the first place.

Comment: BPM Suite and jBPM are two different things. Instances can be started by a REST call and you can pass attributes to this call as process variables. The actor/group fields are simple comma separated strings.

You need to use the Administator account (or another) to create a process instance, but you can assign tasks to a "string" user which is outside the BPM Suite user hierarchy.

Comment: When you say "logged", you mean logged to what? BPM Suite/Console? Your application? A REST client?

Comment: Hi, considering the example URL you have shared in the answer "http://user:password@server.address.com/business-central/rest". I want to get "user" in the activities of the process without passing it as input. Is it possible?

Comment: There isn't a documented method to get an User or a collection of them. However if you know the User to make the REST api call, you could pass the same string as a parameter (process variable) when you start a new process instance and then use that variable as a parameter in your REST service task.

Comment: Yes going ahead with the same approach.. Thanks. Post your response as an answer so that I can mark this thread as closed.